# Is "please be reminding" valid usage?

Tags: grammar, gerund-vs-infinitive

I received mail from my colleague. He wrote,

> Please be reminding that...

I am confused about this. I think it should be more passive, like this,

> Please be reminded that...

Which is correct?

Comment: Please provide the sentence in full context in order to receive a complete and correct answer

Comment: Normal usage would be  *Please remember the forms are due tomorrow.* or *Please remember that the forms are due tomorrow.*

Comment: More information is required: in most varieties of English this is ungrammatical, but in Indian English (I believe) this _may_ be acceptable.

Comment: The question 'Is _Please be reminded to ..._ a valid construction?' was addressed [here](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/47638/is-please-be-reminded-to-a-valid-construction). 'Please be advised that ...' is certainly common.

Comment: You could also say "please be mindful of..." e.g. a deadline

Comment: @msam, “(please) be reminded” is a passive imperative, so yes, it is passive. The active imperative would be “please remind”, which is of course not relevant here.

Comment: ... and both 'Please be advised that ...' and 'Please be reminded that ...' are illogical (requests to a _non_-potential-agent), but 'Please be advised that ...' is idiomatic, meaning 'We hope you don't mind us advising you that ...'.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I'd have thought that in this case both "advised" and "reminded" were stative, i.e. "(you) be advised/reminded" = "enter the state of being advised/having received advice/having been reminded"

Comment: @msam The normal passives (We were informed / reminded / instructed / apprised / misinformed / taught ... that) are fine, of course. But the passive imperative ([be safe –] get inoculated // don't be fooled!) is a rare beast. 'Please be advised that ...' is accepted jargon; 'Please be reminded that ...' sounds off to me, and I've certainly never come across an adjectival (stative) interpretation of 'reminded'.

Comment: I can find no evidence that using ***remind*** instead of ***remember*** is characteristic of ["Indian English"](http://english.stackexchange.com/tags/indian-english/info), so I've removed the tag.

Answer (score 1):

The correct phrasing is "please be reminded (that)."A more common alternative is "please remember (that)," though.

"May I/we remind you that" is also an acceptable option in formal prose.

Answer (score 0):

It is always helpful to know the context of the sentence and who the intended audience is; however normally you would say "please remember that" or "I would like to remind you that."